# How to update gps location frequently?

Tags: android, gps

I am writing an application that shows your location in a google map...
so far, so good... It does shows my location correctly

The problem is that this gps is not updated if I am moving (or it does, but only after some time)

Does anybody know how to do this in a way like the native google maps (for android) does?
This is, if you click on 'my location' it shows a flashing blue point that changes as you move...

This is my code:

```
//Initializing the listeners        
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 35000, 10, networkLocationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 10, gpsLocationListener);



//and now, in both 'networkLocationListener' and 'gpsLocationListener'
//I overwrite the method 'onLocationChanged':

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("test", "New network location: "+location.getLatitude()+
                  " , "+location.getLongitude());
    myLongitude= location.getLongitude();
    myLatitude= location.getLatitude(); 
}

//and the variables myLongitude and myLatitude are the only ones that I need to display my
//position in the map...
```

Does anybody knows if I am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

The method call you are using is [`requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29), and you're telling it to only give you updates every 35000ms or every 35 seconds. Try lowering that number to whatever suits you. A lower number will mean more battery usage though.

If you want an indicator on a `MapView`, look into [`MyLocationOverlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to leave it like this forever, but it might be worth setting the minTime and minDistance values to zero if you haven't given that a shot yet.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);
```

> If minTime is greater than 0, the LocationManager could potentially rest for minTime milliseconds between location updates to conserve power. If minDistance is greater than 0, a location will only be broadcasted if the device moves by minDistance meters. To obtain notifications as frequently as possible, set both parameters to 0.

-[requestLocationUpdates Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29)